# Why do custom javascript variables in Google Tag Manager run multiple times

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to understand why the custom javascript in Google Tag Manager is firing unexpectedly often. Ultimately, the tag is only firing once, as expected, so it's not problematic, I'm just looking to understand it and if there is a more efficient way I can do it.

I started with a blank container on Google Tag Manager.

I created 3 simple custom javascript variables:

Test - Category

```
function()
{
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer)));
  console.log("Category fired");
  return "Category";
}
```

Test - Action

```
function()
{
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer)));
  console.log("Action fired");
  return "Action";
}
```

Test - label

```
function()
{
  console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(window.dataLayer)));
  console.log("Label fired");
  return "Label";
}
```

I created a GA event tag in GTM:

- Tag type: Google Analytics: Universal Analytics
- Track type: Event
- Category: {{Test - Category}}
- Action: {{Test - Action}}
- Label: {{Test - Label}}

And the trigger is 'all clicks'.

I put Tag Manager into preview mode and tested.

As soon as the page has loaded, before I've made any clicks, the console logs:

> [{}] Array (length: 1)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> [{}] Array (length: 1)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> Label fired
>
> [{}] Array (length: 2)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> [{}] Array (length: 2)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> Label fired
>
> [{}] Array (length: 3)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> [{}] Array (length: 3)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> Label fired

When I make one single click, console log:

> [{}] Array (length: 4)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> [{}] Array (length: 4)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> [{}] Array (length: 4)
>
> Category fired
>
> Action fired
>
> Label fired

On page load, the first 2 variables (category and action) are firing twice for every push to the data layer, while the 3rd (label) just fires once.

On click (a single push to the data layer), the first 2 variables (category and action) fired 3 times, and the third (label) fired just once.

Can anyone explain why the first 2 variables are being evaluated multiple times for each push to the data layer?

Answer (score 1):

When you're in Preview/Debug mode, every variable gets evaluated with every event that is pushed into the data layer.

Comment: So you're saying that when a tag is fired, every variable is evaluated regardless of whether that variable is relevant for that tag? That would make some sense - because we have a page view event firing on page load, so that would explain why the javascript is running on page load, but it still doesn't explain why it ran **12** times? Also, are you saying this only happens in preview mode?

Comment: I ran the tests in a slightly different way, which provides a clearer picture of what's going on and have re-written the question to suit.

Comment: In the preview panel, click on one of the events that have been pushed into the data layer (regardless if you have a tag associated with that event every variable gets evaluated at every event in debug/preview) and then look at the variables tab. That will show you every variable you have and the value it was evaluated to at that event (again, this every event-variable evaluation only happens in debug/preview). Without access it's hard to say why something is/isn't occurring, but that is the path you should go down.

Answer (score 0):

The variable is updated when it's needed e.g.

1. When used within a trigger it resolves within **each** Event.
2. When it's used within a tag only it resolves when it's called within that tag.

This is a good writeup of how variables work:
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/#technical-details-and-how-to

For your problem it might be better to define your main events what you want to tag. Tagging everything does not really have much use and you might be better of using a good heatmap tool like for example Clarity.

Based on the insights from your heatmap tool, you capture relevant events and use that in your reporting.